Program getting randomly stuck during REST API calls in python
I have python code which makes REST API calls and also connects to a websocket.
Every now and then the code gets stuck for many minutes and when I trigger any event on the terminal window (like maximize it or restore its size), then the code suddenly wakes up and starts executing further.
It's the same code which runs every day and its the same loop which is run every minute. Most of the time it runs fine and gets stuck only on some days.
I tried using hanging_threads library but it doesnt help. It tells me about code getting stuck only in my sleep() calls which I myself have added in the code.
from hanging_threads import start_monitoring
start_monitoring(seconds_frozen=10, test_interval=100)
